# Is this question appropriate for this group?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/interpreting-gps-signals-from-auxiliary-3-5mm

I asked this question in the ham radio stack, and they suggested seeing if maybe this group finds it appropriate to post here?
Thank you!

Comment: The page was removed